# How do I get the navigation bar to span the width of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have looked a few questions so far that are very similar to this one, but still can't find the answer to my question. (Please note that I am new to HTML and that this is my first post).

I want to have a navigation bar that spans the width of the page no matter the width of the screen that it is being viewed on. I tried making the 's width 100%, but it still did not do anything.

The code for the navigations bar is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

nav {
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #9b9b9b;
}

a:active {
    color: #ff0000;
} 

</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please help me to find a way to make the navigation bar span the width of the page?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears to be spanning the width of the page.  I put your code into a codepen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNxBME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expand the `li` to be the same size and fill the width of the `ul`, `flexbox` can do that.

**Modern Browsers - Flexbox**

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
}

li {
    flex:1 0 auto;
}

a {
    display: block;
    /*width: 60px;*/
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:10px 0;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #9b9b9b;
}

a:active {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Alternative Solution: Old Browsers - CSS Tables**

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
}
a {
  display: block;
  /*width: 60px;*/
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
}
a:active {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Also, how did you get it to show and hide the code snippet, and run the code snippet when you expand it?

Comment: When you make a snippet there's checkbox you can tick that collapses the snippet. You just have to check it on.

Answer (score 0):

You have already given your nav a width of 100%. Now try adding a width to your LI element in your CSS to evenly distribute them across the 100% width of the nav.

```
li {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nav is already 100% width,with this css configuration.Give it some background you will be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

So right how, the navigation bar is spanning the width of the page, however the objects inside aren't large enough to fill the gap. This can be seen if you add a background color to the navigation bar. What you might consider is center-aligning the objects within the nav bar or expanding the width of each object to near 25%

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the `nav` tag expand from window edge to window edge?

If so you will want to remove the margin on your body:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```